# Grails not encoding the unicode characters properly

Tags: grails, unicode

In my grails app, the unicode characters are not being encoded properly.

I'm using grails 1.3.7 and tomcat 7.0.22. Following are the settings that I've configured in my app for unicode support:

```
- Set grails.views.gsp.encoding and grails.converters.encoding="UTF-8" in Config.groovy
- Set encoding to UTF-8 in meta tag in the .gsp pages
- Specified 'useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8' to the MySql connection URL (DB has characterset set to UTF-8)
- Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" to the server.xml file in tomcat
- Specified the attribute accept-charset="UTF-8" of the form tag.
```

But still, when I submit a unicode character, grails doesn't support the character and the garbled value is being saved. I've googled around and have read ppl asking for help on this same issue but unfortunately the solutions don't work for my favor. Although, I've found a workaround to this problem. The following expression

```
params.detail = params.detail ? new String(params.detail.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8") : null
```

will correctly encode the unicode character.

However, using this approach is tedious since I will have to do this to all the text inputs in my app. Why is the unicode character not being properly encoded by grails and/or tomcat? I think I have the correct settings.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Post actually.

Comment: What browser says about page encoding?

Comment: Yah, the browser correctly encodes the unicode characters.

Comment: Ok, I mean what do you have for `curl --head %YOURSITE%`?

Comment: It shows sth. like 
    `Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1`
    `Location: http://local.everest.com:9090/`
    `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Comment: Does it means that your server doesnt's responds with any concrete encoding and even with content-type? are you sure?

Comment: The server responds in some unconventional encoding format. But still, as I mentinoed earlier in my question, `params.detail = params.detail ? new String(params.detail.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8") : null` correctly renders the unicode character if the `detail` has any unicode character on it.

Comment: I just tried to understand roots of your problem. Ok, I don't insist

Comment: I am ready to provide you with other info should the info that I've provided so far is meager to you. But anyways thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not using Mysql but the HSqlDB which is shipped as default, you will not see 
your encoding problems. The problems occurs due to Mysql, InnoDB and UTF-8.

Since you are using a Mysql Connection and already setting
`useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the MySql connection URL

you still have to add a special hibernate dialect for InnoDB and UTF-8:

`Datasource.groovy` should contain:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {         
            ......
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = "com.domain.mysql.dialect.MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect"
            .....
```

Create a new File in `src/java/com/domain/mysql/dialect/MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect.java`

```
package com.domain.mysql.dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect;

/**
 * Sets the default charset to UTF-8.
 */
public class MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect extends MySQLInnoDBDialect {

    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    }
}
```

Make sure your `Config.groovy` has:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

And your views/layouts/main.gsp starts with:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Greets,

Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, but my schema is of type 'MyISAM'

Comment: My `Config.groovy` has:
`grails.views.default.codec = "html";grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8";grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"`
My `view/layout/main.gsp` has: `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>`

Comment: well, even that doesn't work for me. I even have changed my `meta` tag to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which webxml plugin do you have?Try with at least version 1.4

Comment: @Jan Weitz Thank you!!! Surprised this answer hasn't received more votes. The custom MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect was exactly what I was looking for to get rid of latin1 and convert the tables to utf8. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the Dialect to UTF-8 is not going to work. You have to also modify the tables or the columns of your table to support UTF-8.

Here is the command to alter the table

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or you can try to just modify the column in which you want to store utf-8

using the command

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: is there a way to declare this encoding via a mapping on the domain class?