# How to change encoding for a column in Grails Domain

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

For one of my domain fields I'd like to change the Encoding and Collation. Right now everytime I restart the app, with `dbCreate=create`, I have to manually change the Encoding in the MySQL DB.

```
Encoding: UTF-Unicode
Collation: utf8_bin
```

Is there a way to do this from the domain itself? like from static mapping?

Comment: You have only a column with a different collation or the entire database?

Comment: only a column not the entire database. I guess I could make the entire database UTF-8 but I don't have that immediate need

Comment: I believe you'd better set the whole database to Unicode - it's ways easier to do.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511497/grails-not-encoding-the-uniocde-characters-properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to define default DB encoding in connection URL like:

```
dataSource.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: I believe this only affects the way the server interprets the bytes sent using this connection.  It doesn't affect the charset of the column as OP needs