# Is there a way to change columns Encoding and Collation

Tags: hibernate, grails

For certain fields in my domain class I want the Encoding and Collation changed to `UTF-8` and `utf8_polish_ci` while using MYSql

IS there a way to do this automatically in the datasource or in my domain class? Right now I have to manually change the fields (10) every time I deploy with `create-drop`

I only need this for fields with type `LONGTEXT`

I have mapping for them in my class like this

```
static mapping = {
  myfield type 'text'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can change the encoding in the datasource :

`dataSource.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

(mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511497/grails-not-encoding-the-uniocde-characters-properly) )

But if you only need this only for a certain type of attributes, I'm not sure there's a proper solution...

Defining your own Dialect (as proposed in the link above, or [there](http://blog.tremend.ro/2007/08/14/how-to-set-the-default-charset-to-utf-8-for-create-table-when-using-hibernate-with-java-persistence-annotations/)) will be applied to every domain class...