# How to set useBodyEncodingForURI in Grails bundled tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am a complete newbie in Grails.  My JDBC url (Datasource.groovy) is

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" 
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=yes&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    }
}
```

I have followed the advice in [Grails not encoding the unicode characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511497/grails-not-encoding-the-uniocde-characters-properly) and I manually update a record to Chinese characters.  It is displayed correctly in the browser.  But when I save it back I got garbage.  So I think the database connection is already in UTF-8 but the form data are not decoded in UTF-8.  The fix seems to be setting useBodyEncodingForURI but I cannot find a server.xml file in the Grails bundle.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no server.xml - everything is configured programmatically. There are a few hooks where you can make some changes, so this is actually very straightforward.

Create a file named `_Events.groovy` in your app's `scripts` folder. Add this code:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
   tomcat.connector.useBodyEncodingForURI = true
}
```

That's a Grails/Gant event callback handler for the `ConfigureTomcat` event, which sends the `org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat` instance that manages a lot of the logic for an embedded startup. It's the same code as a server install of the same version, but with a few helper classes to make things easier.

Quickly poking around the API you see that the `Tomcat` instance has a `getConnector` accessor for the `Connector` that's configured as the port 8080 HTTP 1.1 connector, and also remove items, but that in regular Tomcat, and similarly here.

In addition to editing existing configured classes, you can register new servlets, filters, even whole WAR files.

Comment: That looks very promising. But I can't reach that computer until two days later. I'll accept this answer after proof. Thanks again.